# "Вместо того(,) чтобы" внутри вставной конструкции

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы

> А потом – вместо того, чтобы поступить в университет и заниматься
>   наукой, – я оказалась в театре и играла.

Comment: Постановка двух тире не является стандартным решением, но (это мое чисто интуитивное заключение) подчеркивает неожиданность и необычность произошедшего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**А потом – вместо того чтобы поступить в университет и заниматься наукой – я оказалась в театре и играла.**

Автор **имеет полное  право оформить придаточное предложение в виде вставки**, в этом случае его выделительная способность  (при обособлении тире) значительно выше. Он подбирает форму, как художник подбирает краски, ему совершенно необязательно копировать грамматику других текстов.

Только **запятую не надо ставить**, так как на месте вставки не было знаков.

**Примечание:** я оказалась в театре и играла (в спектаклях). Фраза выглядит незаконченной.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы оформила предложение так:

**А потом, вместо того чтобы поступить в университет и заниматься наукой, я оказалась в театре и играла.**

Смысла ставить тире особо не вижу. Союз в данном случае не расчленяется, так как придаточная часть находится внутри главной. Примеры:

*Он, несмотря на то что был в упоительном чаду пива и вина, чувствовал, что несколько неприлично в таком виде и при таком действии находиться в присутствии постороннего свидетеля.* Н. Гоголь, Невский проспект. *Все возы, потому что на них лежали большие тюки с шерстью, казались очень высокими и пухлыми.* А. Чехов, Степь. *Художник, оттого что выпил два стакана портеру, как-то вдруг опьянел и неестественно оживился.* А. Чехов, Припадок.

Answer (score 2):

Союз *вместо того(,) чтобы* в данном случае не расчленяется, потому что придаточная часть находится внутри главной, – запятые ставятся перед союзом и после всего придаточного предложения:

> *А потом,* **вместо того чтобы поступить в университет и заниматься наукой**, *я оказалась в театре и играла*.

По-моему, тире здесь излишни. Это обычное придаточное.

Некоторые похожие примеры:

> Он, **несмотря на то что был в упоительном чаду пива и вина**, чувствовал, что несколько неприлично в таком виде и при таком действии находиться в присутствии постороннего свидетеля. *Н. Гоголь, Невский проспект.*
>
> Сказавши это, он, **вместо того чтобы идти домой**, пошел совершенно в противную сторону, сам того не подозревая. *Н. Гоголь, Шинель.*

Условия (не)постановки запятой, разрывающей составной союз: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach3.